# Gaining an explicit relation from an implicit equation

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, approximation-theory

Given is the following equation:

$\cot(w \tau) = w$

Using the taylor series of cotangens, one can approximate

$\cot(w \tau) \approx \frac{1}{w \tau} - w \tau$

under the assumption $w \tau \ll 1$.

Thus, we get

$w \approx \frac{1}{w \tau} - w \tau$,

which can be solved to

$w \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau (\frac{1}{3} \tau + 1)}}$,

considering only the positive solution.

My question:

The equation $\cot(w \tau) = w$ has infinitely many solutions $w(\tau)$. With the approximation above, we get only one relation. Is there any possibility to gain Information on the other solutions? Numerically, I can find that their algebraic structure is similar to $w \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau (\frac{1}{3} \tau + 1)}}$.